# android content provider-permissions

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

For an application to use a content provider, it needs to mention the permissions in the manifest file. Suppose say it has read_sms permission in its manifest file. And now it wants to read the sms. How does the content resolver/or which ever function/class check if it has the permission to read the sms. checkpermission method in Packagemangerservice checks permissions right, how does the content resolver or the query function direct it to this function to check if the application has a permission?

Answer (score -1):

Why is that relevant to you?
I say just try to do whatever it is you want.\
If your app has permission it will succeed, if not it will throw an 'Access denied exception'.
Be sure to catch it and proceed accordingly.

And btw how would you not know what permissions you app has in your manifest file... i don't get it.

Comment: No, i am not writing an app which uses a content provider. For my project, i need to give a false resource to the application which accesses a content provider. So i want to modify the code where the check happens(check to see if the application has so and so permission). android.content.context has a checkCallingPermission function but i do not know how the control passes to it.